# Facing problems while creating a react application in a visual studio code

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am the new person to try my hands on a react application.
So I followed the basic steps required to create a react file.
I typed:
npx create-react-app my-app and press enter and then I received the following msg:

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

added 1392 packages in 3m

203 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

I am not receiving a success message even after waiting for 2 to 3 hours long.
Please help me with this if anyone could configure it.

Comment: you should go into the project folder and then run the npm command. Like here navigate to my-app folder and run "npm run build" once it is completed use "npm start"

Answer (score 0):

if the package installed then you need to cd into my app and then type npm start

```
cd my-app
npm start
```

and try to add this code to package.json. You could either change the name of your application script to server.js or add the following to your package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node your-script.js"
}
```

> If there is a server.js file in the root of your package, then npm
> will default the start command to node server.js.

refer doucmentation

Comment: PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\NewFolder\my-app> npm start
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:                        ///////////////////////////////////////
npm ERR!   npm run                                                  //////////////////////////////////////    (I cannot see the required files and the correct msgs)

Comment: show your server.js file

Answer (score 0):

try this add this code to your package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node your-script.js"
}
```